# Linking a C++ static library twice in the library dependency tree

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, linker-errors

I've a c++ static library "X.lib" which is statically linked to another C++ static library "A.lib".

I've a huge project "P" which has many DLLs like D1.dll, D2.dll ...D100.dll.
Every DLL links to A.lib.

**However, if i don't give "X.lib" in the list of library dependencies for the linker in the make file of every DLL, linker complaints as "unresolved external external".**

> My query is why do we need to again provide "X.lib" as a dependency
>   library in make file of each DLL when we have already provide "X.lib" as a
>   dependency in the make file of "A.lib", and A.lib anyhow is there in
>   the list of library dependencies in each DLL's make file.

Comment: Are you really linking something to static library? You compile and pack together object files. No linking.

Comment: You can't link static libs to static libs; you can however merge static libraries using a library manager.  This does not link them just puts all the obj(s) into the same container (lib). Note that a static lib is just a convenient container of obj(s) no linking is involved.

Comment: @RichardCritten: thanks.